# Is IntelliJ showing wrong code completion?

Tags: intellij-idea, methods, parameters

I encountered some weird behaviour with latest version of IntelliJ IDEA. I have small private java library, and when I try to use it in other project, IntelliJ shows wrong method parameter names. More here on the picture:
[wrong IntelliJ code completion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMloS.png)

Notice that when I do it like this it works as it should:
[good intellij code completion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGzeM.png)

Can I configure the IDE so it would display it like on the second picture, or is it a bug/intended behaviour?

Edit:

Combinatorics is an interface. CombinatoricsImpl is class implementing that interface and have method getCombinatorics, that return new instance of CombinatoricsImpl.

```
public static Combinatorics getCombinatorics() {
    return new CombinatoricsImpl();
}
```

Interface (without javadoc):

```
public interface Combinatorics {

    double combinationsNonRepeating(int n, int k);

    double variationsNonRepeating(int n, int k);

    double permutationsNonRepeating(int n);

    double combinationsRepeating(int n, int k);

    double variationsRepeating(int n, int k);

    double permutationsRepeating(List<Integer> frequencies);
}
```

Comment: You don't use the same code in the two examples. Can you add the original code here?

Comment: Thats the point i think, that in one case it works and when i write it the other way it does not work.

Comment: I understand, but adding the code would help us help you

Comment: It might be merely a bug.
Please take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377331/generating-code-stub-from-class-and-javadoc).

Comment: So it is probably bug, checked it and Netbeans do not have such issue.

Answer (score 0):

The method getCombinatorics() is not return an object of type Combinatorics. That is why it is not working in the first image.

In the second image, you are casting it into an Combinatorics object type. So it is working in the second image.

I don't think there is anything wrong with the ide here.

Comment: That method return instance of class that implements interface Combinatorics (i added some code to my original post). In Netbeans IDE this work without problem so i think it is bug in IDEA.